# Howto synchronize two folders (on different servers) after an (classic) ASP upload

Tags: asp-classic, synchronization, windows-server

I'm using a customized backend to upload images on a server.

The issue is that the client has a load balanced server so I need to synchronize the upload folders on both server. I'm not able to know which server is executing on the backend.

I'm just wondering which is the best way to compare and synchronize the folders on two servers? An FTP script using the windows "cron-job"? A shell script activated by ASP? Aa ASP script that uses FTP commands?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your servers are on the same network you could do this with a utility like ROBOCOPY
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

Also you might be able to use DFS replication.